# Path to publishing a technical book

Tags: technical-writing

I'm 21 years old female from South India. I would like to publish a book which concentrates on any one latest computer technology. Now, I have completed my BE- Computer Science and Engineering. I'm going to work in an IT company for two years and after 4 years I would like to publish the book. What are the qualifications I need to publish a technical-oriented book? What is the procedure for that? Is it way too expensive? I don't have anyone for guidance. Kindly guide me.

Comment: First draft it out on Google Sites and gauge its responses and then use Amazon publishing to publish a more complete version. BTW, do not use colloquialism like "going to" in technical writing, such as "going to go to work" or "going to going to go to work". Use "I will be", "I shall", "I should", "I will need to".

Comment: @BlessedGeek Thank you so much for your correction, Sir. I will improve myself Sir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three things you need to publish such a book:

1. Mastery of the subject matter.
2. The ability to write well, in an engaging, informative style and samples to prove that.
3. A publisher.

The usual practice is to get an idea for a book that has not been covered to death, write a proposal, and submit it to various publishers along with samples of your writing on similar subjects. Blog writing on that or other topics will help, but be aware that the coverage should be thorough and detailed, not just a "random thoughts" kind of thing.

If you are a recognized expert in your field, so much the better. You may receive inquiries from publishers without solicitation. Absent that, you should be prepared for plenty of rejection.

Comment: So, while sending a proposal to a publisher, we need not have the complete copy of the book?

Comment: You are much better off *not* having a complete copy of the book. Publishers want to shape the books they publish to address needs they have, and that is far easier to do at the proposal stage. Note that technical publishers frequently assign parts of books to several authors. Writing part of a book is a good step toward getting the credentials to write an entire book yourself.